# Sitecore WFFM - increase email character limit from 30

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

Email field is not allowing to enter more than 30 characters. How can I increase the allowed field length?

In validation only "Count char" and "regular expression" is specified there. Where the default limit is given for email? please suggest.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more to information.. to start with: are you talking about WFFM?

Comment: Yes, it is web form for marketers

Comment: I have a WFFM on v8 here but can't reproduce this behavior. Can you check and share your field type, validation set on the field, the regex used in the email validation (if email field), the error message that you get (is it client-side validation or server-side validation that is giving the error ?)

Comment: I am also using WFFM on v8. I have created a form with multiple fields including email. Now when I am filling the form, it’s not allowing me to enter more than 30 characters in that email field (no error message, can't type after 30 characters). I checked in the WFFM --> settings  --> field types --> simple types --> Email (There are 2 validations, first is regular expression for email "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" and another is "Count Char"). I can see <DynamicStringLengthErrorMessage> but not sure how it works